# how to detect sound from video with javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm making educational program for someone who study foreign languages.
For some reasons, i want to add event when someone start speech in the video.
is there any possible things that i can do?

Comment: Use the speech recognition API though that will also detect if the user starts talking

Comment: Three upvotes for this question?